# What indices could is use for coastline extraction using rapideye imagery

Tags: remote-sensing, ndvi

I am currently writing a proposal to get RapidEye imagery for my master thesis. In this proposal I am trying to explain what I am doing. Except NDVI/NDVI-RedEdge and NDWI, can anyone suggest some other index (applicable for Rapideye imagery) that could help me with coastline extraction?